# CSS focus-within and hover are not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, hover, focus

I'm trying to display the search tags (the buttons above the text input field) when the search bar under them is clicked. I've tried to solve the problem with :hover :focus and :focus-within, but none of them seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```css
.container {
   margin: 0 0;
   padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
   padding-top: 5vh;
   overflow: auto;
 }

 .up_buttons {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 200px);
   justify-content: center;
   padding: 10px;
   grid-gap: 20px;
   visibility: hidden;
 }

 .dwn_buttons {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 200px);
   justify-content: center;
   padding: 20px;
   grid-gap: 20px;
   visibility: hidden;
 }

 #bar:focus .dwn_buttons .up_buttons {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 200px);
   justify-content: center;
   padding: 20px;
   grid-gap: 20px;
   visibility: visible;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <div class="up_buttons">
      <div class="tp_btn">
        <input type="button" id="btn5" value=" food " />
      </div>
      <div class="tp_btn">
        <input type="button" id="btn6" value=" wtf do I know " />
      </div>
      <div class="tp_btn">
        <input type="button" id="btn7" value=" just an idea " />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dwn_buttons">
      <div class="tp_btn">
        <input type="button" id="btn8" value=" social media content " />
      </div>
      <div class="tp_btn">
        <input type="button" id="btn9" value=" branding " />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sbar" id="bar">
      <input type="text" placeholder=" What's in your head?">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:focus-within` and `:hover` or other state not worked for previous sibling selector. Instead you can use root element to check in focus-within the `.container` in your case. That way you can change style of all child element of the root element, `.container` in your case.

```css
.container {
   margin: 0 0;
   padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
   padding-top: 5vh;
   overflow: auto;
 }

 .up_buttons {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 200px);
   justify-content: center;
   padding: 10px;
   grid-gap: 20px;
   visibility: hidden;
 }

 .dwn_buttons {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 200px);
   justify-content: center;
   padding: 20px;
   grid-gap: 20px;
   visibility: hidden;
 }
 .container:focus-within .dwn_buttons,
 .container:focus-within .up_buttons{ 
   visibility: visible;
 } 
 .container:hover .dwn_buttons,
 .container:hover .up_buttons{ 
   visibility: visible;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <div class="up_buttons">
      <div class="tp_btn">
        <input type="button" id="btn5" value=" food " />
      </div>
      <div class="tp_btn">
        <input type="button" id="btn6" value=" wtf do I know " />
      </div>
      <div class="tp_btn">
        <input type="button" id="btn7" value=" just an idea " />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dwn_buttons">
      <div class="tp_btn">
        <input type="button" id="btn8" value=" social media content " />
      </div>
      <div class="tp_btn">
        <input type="button" id="btn9" value=" branding " />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sbar" id="bar">
      <input type="text" placeholder=" What's in your head?">
    </div>
  </div>
```